# How to update recordset in VB6 using DAO connections with sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb6, dao

I am using a VB6 application. Which was using the MSAccess database. Now i am changing the database access to sql server. to getting/updating the data from MSAccess the application was using the DAO object. So now i am also trying to connect SQL Server with DAO method. Now i am able to connect the database and also able to get the data. But when i am trying to Edit record it is giving the error "Runtime error '3027' cannot update. Database or object is read only". i am showing my code here:

```
Public LSWs As Workspace, LSDb As Database
Dim lsConnString As String
Dim l0 As Recordset, SQL0 As String
Dim lehReturn As Integer, retrycount As Integer

lsConnString = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SERVERName;DATABASE=" & DBname & ";APP=Visual Basic;UID=UID;PWD=PWD"
Set LSWs = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set LSDb = LSWs.OpenDatabase(DBname, dbDriverNoPrompt, True, lsConnString) 
retrycount = 0
SQL0 = "select * from schedule_hdr where status = '" & Trim(PCName) & "'"
Set l0 = LSDb.OpenRecordset(SQL0, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, adLockPessimistic)
Do While Not (l0.EOF)
    LSWs.BeginTrans
    l0.Edit
    l0!status = "R"
    l0.Update
    LSWs.CommitTrans
    l0.MoveNext
Loop
l0.Close
```

but it is giving the error at l0.Edit this line code
giving the error
 "Runtime error '3027' cannot update. Database or object is read only
Any Help! or suggesion please reply

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is the transaction `LSWs.BeginTrans` really necessary? You're only updating one record at a time so a transaction won't do anything useful there. Is it possible that you're ODBC connection is read only?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I'm thinking that the username and password you are using for the SQL server may possibly have read-only rights.

If this is not the case and you want to stick with DAO then I suggest using the built-in ODBC link feature of Access as this helps you connect successfully to your SQL server.

However, my advice has to be abandoning DAO and going with ADO, mainly because DAO restricts your data processing to client side which is slow, and the whole point of having a dedicated server is to run as much as you can server side to dramatically improve performance.